# How to create clustered keys in code first

Tags: c#, code-first, data-annotations

A person can have many colleagues and a colleague is a person. Is it possible to make a clustered key on `ColleagueId` and `PersonId`?

Ok, im not really sure but the Colleague class is only there because the database should understand the connection to `Person`. So, actually i dont need the `Colleague` class. How can I do so the database understands that the `Person` has a list of `Colleagues` that is a `Person`?

In the program, we can create `Persons` and then we should be able to add other `Persons` to the `Persons` list of `Colleagues`!

My explanation feels cloudy, but I do not know how to explain it in any other way.

Colleague class:

```
public class Colleague
{
    [Key]
    public int ColleagueId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public virtual Person PersonId { get; set; }
}
```

Person class:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Conversation> Conversations { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Colleague> Colleague { get; set; }


    public Person()
    {
        Conversations = new List<Conversation>();
        Colleague = new List<Colleague>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically want a many-to-many relationship between `Person` entities. For this you would need a junction table which links pairs of `Person` entities. If we call this entity `WorkRelationship`:

```
class WorkRelationship
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("Myself")]
    public int MyselfId { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Myself { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [ForeignKey("Colleague")]
    public int ColleagueId { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Colleague { get; set; }
}
```

Then we modify `Person` like so:

```
class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Myself")]
    public virtual ICollection<WorkRelationship> WorkRelationships { get; set; }

    public void AddWorkRelationship(Person colleague)
    {
        if (WorkRelationships == null)
        {
            WorkRelationships = new List<WorkRelationship>();
        }

        WorkRelationships.Add(new WorkRelationship { Myself = this, Colleague = colleague });
    }
}
```

So you can see that `Person` now has a collection of `WorkRelationships`: by adding an entity to this collection, you not only link this person to his/her colleague, but also create the inverse relationship. I've also added a helper method so that you can easily add a relationship.

Here's a very basic database context class that can be used to manage these entities:

```
sealed class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WorkRelationship> WorkRelationships { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Person> GetColleagues(int personId)
    {
        List<WorkRelationship> relationships =
            WorkRelationships
            .Include(x => x.Myself)
            .Include(x => x.Colleague)
            .Where(x => x.MyselfId == personId || x.ColleagueId == personId)
            .ToList();

        foreach (WorkRelationship relationship in relationships)
        {
            if (relationship.Myself.Id == personId)
            {
                yield return relationship.Colleague;
            }
            else if (relationship.Colleague.Id == personId)
            {
                yield return relationship.Myself;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    }
}
```

I've also added a helper method to this that will retrieve the colleagues of a given person.

We can now create a simple test program to insert and query people:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var alice = new Person { Name = "Alice" };
    var bob = new Person { Name = "Bob" };
    var colin = new Person { Name = "Colin" };
    var davina = new Person { Name = "Davina" };

    alice.AddWorkRelationship(bob);
    alice.AddWorkRelationship(colin);

    bob.AddWorkRelationship(davina);

    using (var db = new MyContext())
    {
        db.People.AddRange(new[] { alice, bob, colin, davina });
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    using (var db = new MyContext())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bob works with:");
        foreach (Person colleague in db.GetColleagues(bob.Id))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(colleague.Name);
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

---

**Original answer below** (included for context)

If a `Colleague` *is-a* `Person`, then you should model it like that:

```
public class Colleague : Person
{
    // don't need any other properties based on what you've posted
}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Conversation> Conversations { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Colleague> Colleagues { get; set; }
}
```

(I have pluralized the property name used to hold the collection of colleagues).

EF Code First should then create a single `Person` table with an extra `Discriminator` column used to distinguish between `Person` and `Colleague` entities.

Thinking about it a little more, I'm not even sure you need the separate `Colleague` entity. You could probably get away with this:

```
public class Person
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Colleagues { get; set; }
}
```

Note `ICollection<Person>` instead of `ICollection<Colleague>`.

Comment: So if I use this. Can i load a `Person` who has a list of `Colleagues` from the database?

Comment: Something like `db.People.Where(x => x.Colleagues.Count > 0)` should return you a list of `Person` entities that have colleagues assigned to them (I haven't tested this but I think it should work).

Comment: Ok, im not really sure but the `Colleague` class is only there because the database should understand the connection to `Person`.

Comment: Maybe you could add some detail to your question explaining what you plan on doing with `Colleague` entities? At the moment, based on what you've said, a colleague is just a person who is related to another person, presumably because they work together. I don't think you need a separate entity for that.

Answer (score 1):

I use OrmLite v3 (which does not support complex primary keys). The work around I use there is to create a new property that is a combination of both keys and which I use as a key:

```
public class Colleague
{
    public int ColleagueId { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public string CombinedId {
        get { return ColleagueId.ToString() + PersonId.ToString(); }
    }
}
```

I use the `string` type to avoid getting the sum of the two `int` values (which can lead to key collisions, although is is not completely safe, depending on the int digits numbers). Of course you can adapt this according to your own types.